# converting jpeg char data to opencv mat

Tags: c++, opencv, tcp, jpeg, mjpeg

i have a mjpeg tcp stream and want to modify it. So i can access the image data via recv-function and save it in a char-buffer.

```
//....
const int buf_size = 512;
char buf[buf_size];
//...
int bytesReceived = recv(sock, buf, buf_size, MSG_WAITALL);
//...
```

Now i can extract the jpeg image data out of the char-array; i created a test char array (16*16 jpeg image):

```
char img[] = {-1,-40,-1,-32,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,-1,-37,0,67,0,5,3,4,4,4,3,5,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,7,12,8,7,7,7,7,15,11,11,9,12,17,15,18,18,17,15,17,17,19,22,28,23,19,20,26,21,17,17,24,33,24,26,29,29,31,31,31,19,23,34,36,34,30,36,28,30,31,30,-1,-37,0,67,1,5,5,5,7,6,7,14,8,8,14,30,20,17,20,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,-1,-64,0,17,8,0,16,0,16,3,1,34,0,2,17,1,3,17,1,-1,-60,0,31,0,0,1,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,-1,-60,0,-75,16,0,2,1,3,3,2,4,3,5,5,4,4,0,0,1,125,1,2,3,0,4,17,5,18,33,49,65,6,19,81,97,7,34,113,20,50,-127,-111,-95,8,35,66,-79,-63,21,82,-47,-16,36,51,98,114,-126,9,10,22,23,24,25,26,37,38,39,40,41,42,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,-125,-124,-123,-122,-121,-120,-119,-118,-110,-109,-108,-107,-106,-105,-104,-103,-102,-94,-93,-92,-91,-90,-89,-88,-87,-86,-78,-77,-76,-75,-74,-73,-72,-71,-70,-62,-61,-60,-59,-58,-57,-56,-55,-54,-46,-45,-44,-43,-42,-41,-40,-39,-38,-31,-30,-29,-28,-27,-26,-25,-24,-23,-22,-15,-14,-13,-12,-11,-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-1,-60,0,31,1,0,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,-1,-60,0,-75,17,0,2,1,2,4,4,3,4,7,5,4,4,0,1,2,119,0,1,2,3,17,4,5,33,49,6,18,65,81,7,97,113,19,34,50,-127,8,20,66,-111,-95,-79,-63,9,35,51,82,-16,21,98,114,-47,10,22,36,52,-31,37,-15,23,24,25,26,38,39,40,41,42,53,54,55,56,57,58,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,-126,-125,-124,-123,-122,-121,-120,-119,-118,-110,-109,-108,-107,-106,-105,-104,-103,-102,-94,-93,-92,-91,-90,-89,-88,-87,-86,-78,-77,-76,-75,-74,-73,-72,-71,-70,-62,-61,-60,-59,-58,-57,-56,-55,-54,-46,-45,-44,-43,-42,-41,-40,-39,-38,-30,-29,-28,-27,-26,-25,-24,-23,-22,-14,-13,-12,-11,-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-1,-38,0,12,3,1,0,2,17,3,17,0,63,0,-15,58,-13,127,26,127,-56,-51,119,-1,0,0,-1,0,-48,22,-109,-2,18,125,115,-2,127,-65,-14,18,127,-123,102,-34,-35,79,121,114,-9,55,47,-26,74,-8,-36,-40,3,56,24,29,61,-123,126,23,-57,-100,121,-105,113,14,93,12,46,22,19,82,83,82,-9,-108,82,-78,-116,-105,73,61,117,93,15,-25,14,42,-30,-84,30,111,-124,-115,10,17,-110,106,73,-22,-107,-83,102,-70,55,-36,-1,-39};
```

The next step is, to create a cv::Mat out of it. I guess i have to use

```
Mat imdecode(InputArray buf, int flags)
```

to achieve this, but i dont know how. I found a solution, but I don't really like it, cause it needs an unnecessary conversion between OpenCV data types:

```
CvMat mat = cvMat(16, 16, CV_8UC3, img);
IplImage *pIplImage = cvDecodeImage(&mat, 1);
cv::Mat mtx(pIplImage); 
cv::imshow("decoded img", mtx);
cvReleaseImage(&pIplImage);
cv::waitKey();
```

Is there a direct way to convert a **signed** char-array to cv::Mat?

edit: 
just to clearify the data format, you can directly save the char-array to a jpeg file and open it with a random image viewer

```
FILE *output;
output = fopen("test.jpg", "wb");
fwrite(img,sizeof(char),sizeof(img),output);
fclose(output);
```

Comment: `cv::imdecode` is the C++ api way and should work on a `std::vector<char>` and/or a `cv::Mat` with `char*` data pointer. But take care, the streaming standard for jpeg images does not include the full jpeg header for each image! Some streaming servers do and others don't include the full header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int
main(int argc,char*argv[])
{
char img[] = {-1,-40,-1,-32,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,-1,-37,0,67,0,5,3,4,4,4,3,5,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,7,12,8,7,7,7,7,15,11,11,9,12,17,15,18,18,17,15,17,17,19,22,28,23,19,20,26,21,17,17,24,33,24,26,29,29,31,31,31,19,23,34,36,34,30,36,28,30,31,30,-1,-37,0,67,1,5,5,5,7,6,7,14,8,8,14,30,20,17,20,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,-1,-64,0,17,8,0,16,0,16,3,1,34,0,2,17,1,3,17,1,-1,-60,0,31,0,0,1,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,-1,-60,0,-75,16,0,2,1,3,3,2,4,3,5,5,4,4,0,0,1,125,1,2,3,0,4,17,5,18,33,49,65,6,19,81,97,7,34,113,20,50,-127,-111,-95,8,35,66,-79,-63,21,82,-47,-16,36,51,98,114,-126,9,10,22,23,24,25,26,37,38,39,40,41,42,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,-125,-124,-123,-122,-121,-120,-119,-118,-110,-109,-108,-107,-106,-105,-104,-103,-102,-94,-93,-92,-91,-90,-89,-88,-87,-86,-78,-77,-76,-75,-74,-73,-72,-71,-70,-62,-61,-60,-59,-58,-57,-56,-55,-54,-46,-45,-44,-43,-42,-41,-40,-39,-38,-31,-30,-29,-28,-27,-26,-25,-24,-23,-22,-15,-14,-13,-12,-11,-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-1,-60,0,31,1,0,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,-1,-60,0,-75,17,0,2,1,2,4,4,3,4,7,5,4,4,0,1,2,119,0,1,2,3,17,4,5,33,49,6,18,65,81,7,97,113,19,34,50,-127,8,20,66,-111,-95,-79,-63,9,35,51,82,-16,21,98,114,-47,10,22,36,52,-31,37,-15,23,24,25,26,38,39,40,41,42,53,54,55,56,57,58,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,-126,-125,-124,-123,-122,-121,-120,-119,-118,-110,-109,-108,-107,-106,-105,-104,-103,-102,-94,-93,-92,-91,-90,-89,-88,-87,-86,-78,-77,-76,-75,-74,-73,-72,-71,-70,-62,-61,-60,-59,-58,-57,-56,-55,-54,-46,-45,-44,-43,-42,-41,-40,-39,-38,-30,-29,-28,-27,-26,-25,-24,-23,-22,-14,-13,-12,-11,-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-1,-38,0,12,3,1,0,2,17,3,17,0,63,0,-15,58,-13,127,26,127,-56,-51,119,-1,0,0,-1,0,-48,22,-109,-2,18,125,115,-2,127,-65,-14,18,127,-123,102,-34,-35,79,121,114,-9,55,47,-26,74,-8,-36,-40,3,56,24,29,61,-123,126,23,-57,-100,121,-105,113,14,93,12,46,22,19,82,83,82,-9,-108,82,-78,-116,-105,73,61,117,93,15,-25,14,42,-30,-84,30,111,-124,-115,10,17,-110,106,73,-22,-107,-83,102,-70,55,-36,-1,-39};

    Mat rawData(1,sizeof(img),CV_8SC1,(void*)img);
    Mat decodedMat= imdecode(rawData,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH);
    imwrite("a.jpg",decodedMat);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!Yeah, kinda, except that it has to be green, this one is just grey ... i guess there is something wrong with "CV_8SC1"?

Comment: Oh, try changing to `-CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR` (with a minus) instead of `CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH`

Comment: 8sc1 is signed int. There probably has to be a 8uc1 instead

Comment: @Micka I think it is correct as it stands - OP says he has signed data.